# Android Volley: own REST Lib

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm a beginner android developer and now I'm facing a big problem using google volley for making http calls. I made my own library to handle all REST API Request and I have to return the response to the ACTIVITY but the call is asynchronous and when I call to return the has not arrives. This is the lib:

```
public class RestServices implements IRestServices {
Object responseFromServer = null;
public Object getJsonResponseObjectByAttributes(String... attributes) {
        RequestQueue queue = VolleyProvider.getQueue(ConnectionConstants.context);
        String finalUri = makeRequestUri(attributes);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, finalUri, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        jsonRequest.setTag(ConnectionConstants.TAG);
        queue.add(jsonRequest);

return responseFromServer;
}
```

And here is where I call the service:

```
public class MainViewModel implements IMainViewModel {

    @Inject IRestServices restServices;

    // Define our server URL
    public static final String SERVER_URL = "API_Url";

    public String getServerResponse() {
        Object jsonResponse = restServices.getJsonArrayResponseObjectByAttributes("");
        User user = (User) jsonResponse;
        return user.toString();
    }

    public void InitializeViewModel(Context context) {
        restServices.InitializeService(SERVER_URL, context);    
    }

}
```

I'm also using Roboguice for IoC. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign the result to your variable and implement a wait until the result is received:

```
public class RestServices implements IRestServices {
    private Object responseFromServer = null;

    public void getJsonResponseObjectByAttributes(String... attributes) {
        RequestQueue queue = VolleyProvider.getQueue(ConnectionConstants.context);
        String finalUri = makeRequestUri(attributes);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, finalUri, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //add this line to update the result
                    responseFromServer = response;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO implement Error handling
                }
            });

        jsonRequest.setTag(ConnectionConstants.TAG);
        queue.add(jsonRequest);
    }
    //added getter for result
    public Object getResponseFromServer(){
        return responseFromServer;
    }
}
```

This is a busy waiting (because it is easier to show how it should work) and consumes a lot of CPU useage. You should replace it with a blocking waiting (Read about Threads methods wait, notify and yield and Locks like semaphore).

```
public String getServerResponse() {
    restServices.getJsonArrayResponseObjectByAttributes("");
    while(restServices.getResponseFromServer() == null){
        //busy waiting to get sure the result is != null after this loop;
        Thread.sleep(10);//add catch
    }
    Object jsonResponse = restServices.getResponseFromServer();
    User user = (User) jsonResponse;
    return user.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for making the lib can be totally isolated from caller with the purpose of reuse it. So is there any way to perform the wait within the lib?

Comment: Yes, add a new method to your `restServices` that calls `getJsonArrayResponseObjectByAttributes` and implements the waiting before returning the result.

Comment: I'm going to try it. I will update with my results. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your solution but the listener never are called so the main thread doesn't recieve the notified. For this reaseon the program remains blocked but reviewing the logs I can see a message that the response arrive ok from server. I don't know why listeners are not fire once the response arrive.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to not return from your method after making the call but instead after the result is there.  Below you will find an example of how to do this, the key to the example is using a future and then doing a future.get(), this code will not continue execution until there is a response from the web service.

```
//fill params
 JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
 params.put("username", username);
 params.put("password", password);

 //create future request object
 RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
 //create JsonObjectRequest
 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, params, future, future);
 //add request to volley
 MyVolley.getRequestQueue().add(jsObjRequest);
 try {
            JSONObject response = future.get();// this is where the process will 
                                                //wait until a result comes back
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return response;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but when future.get() is launched the application gets blocked and the response never arrives. It's seems that when this line is called the main thread is blocked. Thanks!

Comment: future.get() will not prevent the network request from happening.  In general, futures allow you to return an object asynchronously from a method yet continue to do work and put a result into that future object when you are done. This is a fairly accepted practice in backend development and has started becoming more prevalent in android as well. Yes the main thread will get blocked by future.get() but volley does all its network traffic on a different thread and simply puts the result into the future.